# Infinite sum of $e^{-(an + ib)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a solution to the infinite sum:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-(an + ib)^2},$$

where $a$ and $b$ are both real numbers?

I know that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2} = 1/2 (1 + ϑ_3(0, 1/e)) \approx 1.39$$

but I'm not sure how to do the variable change here...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if any closed form exists for this summation.

May be, you could compare with 
$$\int_ 0^\infty  e^{-(an + ib)^2}\,dn=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(\sqrt{a^2}-i\, a\, \text{erfi}(b)\right)}{2 a^2}$$ which you will not find very good since $a=1$ and $b=0$ would lead to $\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}$ which quite far away from $\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\vartheta _3\left(0,\frac{1}{e}\right)\right)$.

In the case where $b=0$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-(an )^2}=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-a^2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: you just have to add the second term of  Euler-MacLaurin and the approximation gets pretty thight (for $a=1,b=0$)

Comment: @tired. Could you elaborate ? Thanks.

Comment: by euler mac laurin, for $f(x)$ being nice enough, we have
$$
\sum_{n=q}^p f(n)=\int_q^p f(x)dx+\frac{1}{2}(f(p)+f(q))+o(max(f(p),f(q)))
$$
in your case $p=0,q=\infty$ and $f(p)=1, f(q)=\infty$.
Therefore with $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+o(1)\approx 1.386
$$
which is pretty close to the exact value